# to block display: none; from a div after i press a div button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

my english is not so good but i try my best to explain my problem and i try like 10 topics to find a solution but im cant figure..

i want after i press this div

```
 <div id="test" class="br3 mb3 ph3 pv2 ba b--black-10 flex justify-between items-center pointer hover-b--primary5">
 <div class="f5 flex items-center">Test1</div>
```

to block the display to show the content of this div

```
 <div id="modal" style="display: none; width: 370px; position: fixed; right: 2px; top: 0; z-index: 99; background-color: white; border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
```

Thanks and have a great day :)

Comment: addEventListener and set the style of the element.

Comment: thanks for reply. also i need help here if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239954/same-form-but-with-another-names-and-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener to when the div is pressed or say `onclick="changeDisplay()"` and add that code to the div you want clicked.

Then add this code to style the div after the function has been issued:

```
  <script>
function changeDisplay() {
    document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: yep working finnaly. god bless you. and thanks for help. also i need help here if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239954/same-form-but-with-another-names-and-functions